# How do i run gzip compression with static huffman ( aka BTYPE=01)

Tags: compression, gzip, fixed, huffman-code

I could not find the gzip command line for generating a compressed output with a fixed/static huffman encoding ( aka BTYPE=01 in the gzip format).
Can someone please help with the options i can use for this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such option. Nor does [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz) have such an option. You can write your own gzipper using [zlib](http://zlib.net), which has a `Z_FIXED` compression strategy that can be provided to `deflateInit2()`. That will force the use of fixed Huffman encoding.